# Returning a Boolean and accessing that information

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I have a small program that I am writing.  I have a few small expressions that I am looking to access from another script.  Problem being is that when I get the return in the inspector (which is correct), the other script doesn't recognize it.  Upon my research, it seems that the void is not the correct return type on the function and I would need something else.

Also, since I am getting the correct return in the inspector, I thought it would be worth mentioning that I get a Null Ref error upon attempting to playing the game on the script that does not recognize the bool

I will be including the code that I am using.  The version of Unity I am using is 5.2.1f1, 64-bit.  Also, I have used Awake and Start.  Neither have worked.  As I didn't think that that would matter, but thought I would give it a shot.

I appreciate the help.

```
public class nonButtonStuff : MonoBehaviour
{

public float timer;
public float tipPercent;
public float checkAmount;

private Seated seated;
private dessert Dessert;
private drinks Drinks;
private food Food;
private appetisers Appetisers;
private checkedUpon checkedOn;



// Use this for initialization
void Awake()
{
    tipPercent = .2f;
    checkAmount = 0;
    seated = GetComponent<Seated>();
    Dessert = GetComponent<dessert>();
    Drinks = GetComponent<drinks>();
    Food = GetComponent<food>();
    Appetisers = GetComponent<appetisers>();
    checkedOn = GetComponent<checkedUpon>();
}

void Update()
{
          if(seated.isSeated == true  && Drinks.drinksOrdered == true || Drinks.drinksOrdered != false && seated.isSeated == false)
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime * 1;
            }

          if(Dessert.Dessert==true)
            {
                timer = 0;
            }
            if (checkedOn.checkedOn > 0)
            {
               Debug.Log(checkedOn);
            }

    }
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~

```
public class Seated : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool isSeated = false;

    public void clicked()
    {

        isSeated = true;
        Debug.Log("Was clicked.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Edited for clarity about the clicked():

I used the built in UI editor to add a button for seated.  So, there's no hard-coded button.  But, when I "play" and click the button, it gives me the boolean as correct.  However, nonButtonStuff doesn't recognize "isSeated" as == true.

Comment: What is it precisely that you are having issues with. If it is a method then the method implements an interface (`update` etc) and then the return value can't be changed

Comment: The exact problem is that nonButtonStuff.cs is not recognizing that there was a change in isSeated bool encoded in Seated.cs.

Comment: @Tim I thought that I had done so when I called it with the "seated=GetComponent<Seated>();"

Comment: When is the `Awake()` method called? Are you sure the `Seated` component exists at that time? Your statement that you get a `NullReferenceException` suggests that the `seated` variable is only ever initialized to the `null` value, and so of course in your `Update()` method the `NullReferenceException` is thrown when you try to access it.

Comment: Unfortunately, without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, or at least a more complete example than the above (it is difficult to provide complete Unity3d examples), it will be difficult if not impossible for anyone to know for sure what the problem is.

Comment: Please check my edit.  I included the full scope of nonButtonStuff.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting a Null Reference Exception, that most likely means that your seated variable (set in the Awake function) is not being set to anything, so the call to GetComponent is failing to find the monobehaviour on the game object. This would happen if your Seated Monobehavior and your nonButtonStuff Monobehavior don't exist on the same GameObject, so be sure that they do.

Comment: This cleared the NullRef error.  That's amazing.  I appreciate that.  I was using two different objects to house these codes.  Thank you very much for that, Kith.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is with isSeated. I think the problem is in the logic of this line:

```
if(seated.isSeated == true  && Drinks.drinksOrdered == true || Drinks.drinksOrdered != false && seated.isSeated == false)
```

You're essentially saying "if isSeated and drinksOrdered or drinks ordered and not seated. That will always return true if drinks are ordered, regardless of the state of isSeated.

Also a note about style. In C# you don't need to compare boolean values using "==" like you're doing. This:

```
if(myBoolean){}
```

is the same code as

```
if(myBoolean == true){}
```

Most people like to write the simpler code so that there is less risk of logic errors. Your code can therefor be rewritten as

```
if(seated.isSeated  && Drinks.drinksOrdered || Drinks.drinksOrdered && !seated.isSeated)
```

Since

```
if(seated.isSeated || !seated.isSeated)
```

well always return true, you can just remove those values. That leaves you with

```
if(Drinks.drinksOrdered || Drings.drinksOrdered)
```

That can be reduced to simply

```
if(Drinks.drinksOrdered)
```

This is the exact same logic as the original code:

```
if(seated.isSeated == true  && Drinks.drinksOrdered == true || Drinks.drinksOrdered != false && seated.isSeated == false)
```

It is just clearer.

Comment: After troubleshooting my logic quite a bit for this instance, I did notice that because I was not being strict on my code, I had set it so that the seated and drinks must return a true.  So, to make it easier, I just did the: **seated.isSeated == true && Drinks.drinksOrdered == false || Drinks.drinksOrdered == true && seated.isSeated == false**

as the timer starter.  Later on, I realized that I wanted more than one timer running at once.  So, I just added a timer for everything that I wanted it for.

Comment: You can reduce "seated.isSeated == true && Drinks.drinksOrdered == false || Drinks.drinksOrdered == true && seated.isSeated == false" to "seated.isSeated != Drinks.drinksOrdered"